# How to handle Xamarin DisplayAlert in a IF construct

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my code:

```
var choice = DisplayAlert("Title", "Delete This?", "YES", "NO");
    if (choice.ToString() == "YES")
    {
        //do something
    }
```

It seems the variable `choice` doesn't assume neither `YES` nor `NO`, but it's a totally different string (something like this: `` System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Boolean] ``). What should I do to make it a proper string or a boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DisplayAlert is an async method and returns a boolean.  Use the await keyword to get that boolean.

```
var choice = await DisplayAlert("Title", "Delete This?", "YES", "NO");
if (choice) //yes was clicked
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`DisplayAlert` is an `async` method, so you need to use the `await` keyword

```
var choice = await DisplayAlert("Title", "Delete This?", "YES", "NO");
if (choice)
{
    //do something
}
```